# mysqld won't start on fedora 22

Tags: mysql, fedora, owncloud

I have a vm running a LAMP stack with Fedora 22. This is a server dedicated to running OwnCloud.

The server and OwnCLoud ran fine for several weeks. I had to reboot the server. On reboot mysqld fails to start. Attempting to manually start the service fails also.

```
[root@cloudServ]/home/rcreasy# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with
error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe"
for details.
```

Here are the results of systemctl status mysqld.service

```
[root@cloudServ]/home/rcreasy# systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2016-09-30 12:03:34 EDT; 1min 3s ago
Process: 3851 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 3829 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling ...art.
Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 30 12:03:34 cloudServ systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'start-limit'.
```

journalctl -xe gives many lines with (where XXX is several different numbers)

```
Sep 30 12:15:12 cloudServ ownCloud[XXX]: {remote} Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or dir
```

Nothing new is written to /var/log/mysqld.log
Ownership on /var/lib/mysql and its contents is mysql:mysql

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you try running `mysqld` by hand do you get any useful error messages?

Comment: What do you mean by "start it by hand"?

Comment: If at a prompt you just try to directly run `mysqld` not through systemd but as a command yourself, perhaps you'll see something useful

Comment: Ahh. Thx. Running mysqld as regular user at the cmd line gave no response at the terminal, and still wrote nothing to the mysqld.log

Comment: Hmm, you might need to run it is root or as the mysql user, and also if you get no output and no meaningful exit status, you could try adding `--debug` to the command and see if that produces a file (probably `/tmp/mysqld.trace`) that has any clues

Comment: Same results. No file at `/tmp/mysqld.trace`

Comment: @EricRenouf thanks so much for your time and help. I did learn from you. I posted the solution I found.

Comment: Remember that Fedora 22 is EOL. Use `dnf system-upgrade` to upgrade to a current supported release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
The hard drive was running out of space. I suppose there was not enough space for MySQL to write to the log, causing it to fail.

Since this is a vm, I added virtual drive space.

Posting this in hopes that it helps someone else, and that my hours of time are of some benefit to someone.